# How to join first result from child table

Tags: java, sqlite

I have a one to many relationship in my SQL table, one movie can have many airings:

Movie -> movie_id, title, ...other fields

Airings -> movie_id, date_time, channel_id

So I want to return a single line based on the movie id, and return inline the top airing sorted on date_time.

Here's what I have so far, but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT m.movie_id, m.title, next_airing.date_time, next_airing.channel_id
FROM movies m

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * 
    FROM movie_airings
    ORDER BY date_time DESC

) next_airing
ON next_airing.movie_id=m.movie_id

WHERE m.movie_id = 2
```

this returns each row in movie_airings with the movie details attached:

```
 movie_id     title         date_time    channel_id
 1            some title    1-11-2011    3
 1            some title    2-11-2011    4
 1            some title    3-11-2011    1
```

Where am I going wrong?  If I use GROUP BY in the inner query I can get it to return the last unsorted airing, but can't get it to return the top sorted airing as having a ORDER BY and GROUP BY doesn't seem to work.

Can you help?

Comment: whats the problem with above ?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT m.movie_id, m.title, next_airing.date_time, next_airing.channel_id
FROM movies m

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * 
    FROM movie_airings
    ORDER BY date_time DESC

) next_airing
ON next_airing.movie_id=m.movie_id

WHERE m.movie_id = 2
LIMIT 1
```